# Obter a soma dos registros da ultima semana laravel

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel, laravel-5.4

Olá, Estou estudando **Laravel** estou usando a **versão 5.4**, preciso de um help porque não estou conseguindo retornar o **total de registros da ultima semana do banco de dados**, consegui retornar o total, e o total do mês, mas o total da ultima semana não.

Deixando claro que o que eu não consegui foi retornar o total de dados dos últimos 7 dias do banco de dados.

Aqui está o meu Controller:

```
public function index(){
        $users = DB::table('clientes')->count(); 

        $semana = date("d")-7;
        $usersemanal = DB::table('clientes')->whereDate('created_at', $semana)->count();

        $mes = date('m');
        $totalusers = DB::table('clientes')->whereMonth("created_at",$mes)->count();    

        return view('dashboard', compact('users', 'totalusers', 'usersemanal'));
    }
```

Esta é a parte do código que eu fiz para retornar a ultima semana mas não consigo chegar a lugar algum.

Alguma solução ou outra forma para fazer este retorno?

```
$semana = date("d")-7;
        $usersemanal = DB::table('clientes')->whereDate('created_at', $semana)->count();
```

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta certa pode variar de acordo com o tipo de dado que seu `created_at` contém, se ele for `dateTime` ou `date` usar o `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` não retornará o resultado esperado ao usa-lo, a menos que o use com o `FROM_UNIXTIME`.

Porque?
Ao usar o `unix_timestamp`, você estará comparando seu campo com um tipo diferente (`date/datetime` com `timestamps`), veja na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Logo, você estará fazendo o seguinte:

```
SELECT * FROM clientes 
         WHERE created_at >= 1559780940
         //onde o created_at será 2019-06-12 00:00:00 por exemplo
```

Veja como seria usando com o `from_unixtime`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde:

```
SELECT * FROM clientes 
         WHERE created_at >= '2019-06-05 21:32:04'
         //onde o created_at será 2019-06-12 00:00:00 por exemplo
```

Com isso, você poderá utilizar o `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` em parceria com o `FROM_UNIXTIME`:

```
$usersemanal = DB::table('clientes')
                        ->whereRaw('created_at >= FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(SUBDATE(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK)))')
                        ->count();
```

Ou tentar formas alternativas e mais simples que também retornarão o resultado que espera:

```
$usersemanal = DB::table('clientes')->whereRaw('`created_at` > (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)')->count();

$usersemanal = DB::table('clientes')->whereRaw('`created_at` > (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK)')->count();

$usersemanal = DB::table('clientes')->whereRaw('`created_at` > SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)')->count();
```

> Referências:
>
> [SUBDATE()](https://database.guide/subdate-examples-mysql/)
>
> [unix_timestamp(), from_unixtime(), date_add(), date_sub() and
>   interval concept in MySQL](http://www.easysolutionweb.com/mysql-tutorials/mysql-unix-timestamp-and-from-unixtime)
>
> [MySQL UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-unix_timestamp-function.php)
>
> [Database: Migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations)
>
> [Where Clauses - Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses)

Answer (score 2):

Já que você já está usando o `Query Builder` você pode usar a seguinte sintaxe:

```php
$usersemanal = DB::table('clientes')
      ->whereRaw('created_at >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK))')
      ->count();
```

Ou se você preferir trazer somente o total

```
$usersemanal = DB::table('users')
        ->select(DB::raw('COUNT(*) as total'))
        ->whereRaw('created_at >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK))')
        ->first();
// debug
dd($usersemanal);
```

**Referências**

- Laravel [whereRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses)
- Laravel [Retrieving A Single Row / Column From A Table](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#retrieving-results)